# groupByTo return emptySet in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have string like this.

```
val input = "perm1|0,perm2|2,perm2|1"
```

Desired output type is

```
val output: Set<String, Set<Long>>
```

and desired output value is

```
{perm1 [], perm2 [1,2] }
```

Here I need empty set if value is `0`. I am using `groupByTo` like this

```
val output = input.split(",")
                  .map { it.split("|") }
                  .groupByTo(
                       mutableMapOf(),
                       keySelector = { it[0] },
                       valueTransform = { it[1].toLong()  }
                   )
```

However the output structure is like this

```
MutableMap<String, MutableList<Long>>
```

and output is

```
{perm1 [0], perm2 [1,2] }
```

I am looking for best way to get desired output without using imperative style like this.

```
val output = mutableMapOf<String, Set<Long>>()
input.split(",").forEach {

    val t = it.split("|")

    if (t[1].contentEquals("0")) {

        output[t[0]] = mutableSetOf()
    }

    if (output.containsKey(t[0]) && !t[1].contentEquals("0")) {

        output[t[0]] = output[t[0]]!! + t[1].toLong()
    }

    if (!output.containsKey(t[0]) && !t[1].contentEquals("0")) {

        output[t[0]] = mutableSetOf()
        output[t[0]] = output[t[0]]!! + t[1].toLong()
    }
}
```

Comment: is this desired output `Set<String, Set<Long>>` ? set cannot hold key value pairs right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [mapValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) to convert values type from `List<Long>` to `Set<Long>`

```
var res : Map<String, Set<Long>> = input.split(",")
    .map { it.split("|") }
    .groupBy( {it[0]}, {it[1].toLong()} )
    .mapValues { it.value.toSet() }
```

And of you want to replace list of `0` with empty set you can do it using `if-expression`

```
var res : Map<String, Set<Long>> = input.split(",")
    .map { it.split("|") }
    .groupBy( {it[0]}, {it[1].toLong()} )
    .mapValues { if(it.value == listOf<Long>(0))  setOf() else it.value.toSet() }
```

Comment: nice, I was trying to avoid intermediate split variable

Comment: in your second variant: was it deliberate to allow `0` in the resulting set if there are more than 1 entry (e.g. `perm1|0,perm1|1` = `perm1 = [0, 1]`)?

Comment: But i did on OP question, if he wants to eliminate 0 for multi param set, he can achive tha by just filtering in if else expression @Roland

Comment: so if I get you correctly, you say: yes, if there are more then 1 value matching a key and one of it is `0` the resulting set will contain that `0`. On the other hand: the resulting set will become an empty set if the only resulting value is `0`. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cannot have Set with key-value pair, result will be of type map. Below code gives sorted set in the values.

```
val result = "perm1|0,perm2|2,perm2|1".split(",")
        .map {
            val split = it.split("|")
            split[0] to split[1].toLong()
        }.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
        .mapValues { it.value.toSortedSet() }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer(s) might be easier to grasp, they build immediate lists and maps in between, that are basically discarded right after the next operation. The following tries to omit that using [`splitToSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split-to-sequence.html#splittosequence) ([Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html)) and [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/grouping-by.html) (see [Grouping bottom part](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-grouping.html)):

```kotlin
val result: Map<String, Set<Long>> = input.splitToSequence(',')
    .map { it.split('|', limit = 2) }
    .groupingBy { it[0] }
    .fold({ _, _ -> mutableSetOf<Long>() }) { _, accumulator, element ->
      accumulator.also {
        it.add(element[1].toLong()))
      }
    }
```

You can of course also filter out the addition of `0` in the set with a simple condition in the `fold`-step:

```kotlin
// alternative fold skipping 0-values, but keeping keys
.fold({ _, _ -> mutableSetOf<Long>() }) { _, accumulator, element ->
  accumulator.also {
    val value = element[1].toLong()
    if (value != 0L)
      it.add(value)
  }
}
```

Alternatively also aggregating might be ok, but then your `result`-variable needs to change to `Map<String, MutableSet<Long>>`:

```kotlin
val result: Map<String, MutableSet<Long>> = // ...
.aggregate { _, accumulator, element, first ->
  (if (first) mutableSetOf<Long>() else accumulator!!).also {
    val value = element[1].toLong()
    if (value != 0L)
      it.add(value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Though this solution does not create temp lists and maps in my test this implementation was slower not sure why.

Comment: How did you test it? The approach with sequence/grouping probably only makes sense with huge input data... and as we do not discard anything on the line, you may only spare the allocated memory of the temporary lists (and exchange it for the allocation of Sequence/Grouping object)...

Comment: This is how I measured it.
```
println(measureNanoTime {

    val b: Map<String, Set<Long>> = input.splitToSequence(',')
            .map { it.split('|', limit = 2) }
            .groupingBy { it[0] }
            .fold({ _, _ -> mutableSetOf<Long>() })
            { _, accumulator, element ->
                accumulator.also {
                    val value = element[1].toLong()
                    if (value != 0L)
                        it.add(value)
                }
            }

}.toString())
```

Comment: well... that's not really a benchmark... if I only use `measureNanoTime` for all the versions shown on this page in an endless loop, every version of this page is the fastest at least once ;-) If you are really interested in benchmarking you may want to use JMH instead... I played around with it and from what I can see, my variant performs slightly better regardless of how big the input string is... however to be honest the impact is negligible in most cases.... best case some ms faster, worst case only some ns faster... but it all depends as always... just measured average time...